# How to send audio file to the server in android?

Tags: php, android

I am writing code to send audio file from android application to the server. The connection is working well, but I don't know how to make the file to save on the server.

My question is : How can I send audio file to server?
Can you please explain me what exactly should I do step by step? I think I am wrong somewhere on the part of encoding file..

```
     public class UploadRecordingAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void, Void>{
         String fileName;
         String filePath;
         String username;

    public UploadRecordingAsyncTask(String filePath, String fileName, String username){
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        try{
            URL url = new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS + "UploadRecording.php");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            //past information
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            //get outputstreamwrite from http connection
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            //write down information
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, ENCODING_FORMAT));

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            //Encoding file part from here
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

            InputStream inputStreamFile = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
            int numOfBytes = inputStreamFile.available();

            byte[] audioBytesFile = new byte[numOfBytes];
            int i = inputStreamFile.read(audioBytesFile,0,numOfBytes);

            String audioString = Base64.encodeToString(audioBytesFile, 0);

            inputStreamFile.close();

            //encode data before sending
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("filename", ENCODING_FORMAT) + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(fileName, ENCODING_FORMAT) + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("owner", ENCODING_FORMAT) + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, ENCODING_FORMAT) + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("encodedfile", ENCODING_FORMAT) + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(audioString, ENCODING_FORMAT) + "&";

            //write data into buffer writer
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            //input stream to get response from the server
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            inputStream.close();

            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

And on the server I have php file :

```
<?php

require "init.php";

if(isset($_POST["encodedfile"])){

$filename = $_POST["filename"];
$owner = $_POST["owner"];

$decoded_string = base64_decode($_POST["encodedfile"]);

$path = "recordings/".$filename;

//new file of audio
$file = fopen($path, 'wb');

to_write_file = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
fclose($file);


    $query = "INSERT INTO Recording (filename, owner, encodedfile) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connectDB, $query)){ 
        /* bind parameters for markers */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $filename, $owner, $decoded_string);
        /* execute line*/
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);   
    }

    mysqli_close($connectDB);

}
?>
```

Comment: in php files are stored in the `$_FILES` global array, not `$_POST`

Comment: Hi alek, welcome to SO. Please have a look at [MCVE] guidelines for asking questions. It makes it a lot easier to answer.

Comment: You need to do this as multi-part form data, or else stream the file through sockets, which is difficult to implement in php I think